# Is there any way to push unilaterally between two CharacterController?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, collider

I have two character controller object using FirstPersonController(UnityStarterAssets). What I want to do is to enable A character to push B character while B character cannot push A.
I tried to use basic rigid body push component, but I think the basic rigid body push componenet does not work between character controller, isn't it?
If it is, how can I make this function..?
(not good at english sry..)